# HTML CSS AdminLTE content wrapper min-height causes side bar to appeared

Tags: html, css, adminlte

How do I remove the `min-height` style at `content-wrapper` class for `AdminLTE`. I am having issue that right side bar is too long and my page does not requires it.

When I debug and close the min-height, everything looks fine.

My code doesn't have `min-height`at the style, I am not sure where it comes from and how i can tweak it.

**Code**

```
<div class="content-wrapper" style="margin: 0px;">

</div>
```

[image: Side bar is too long for the page]

[image: With min-height]

[image: Without min-height, side bar is ok]

**Suggested solutions**

```
.fixed .right-side {
    padding-top: 50px;
    min-height: 100% !important;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is to override the .content-wrapper class.

```
.content-wrapper{
    min-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: I added the above in my AdminLTE.css but still not working, please help.

Answer (score 0):

if you have sidebar menu in your panel and content menu is Higher than main content height , it is ok and you shouldn't change this part because if you change it breakdown your template. if menu's height  is less than main content but you still have scrollbar 
It is because of this aside with main-sidebar class. it has padding style. removed this padding top and add this padding to user-panel class